# How to Delete a column in XLSX file With the help of EPPlus library

Tags: c#

I have one xlsx file in which i have to delete start column and add one new column in the end.
i am using EPPLUS library , but i am not getting any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to download EPPlus Library Documentation:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/downloads/get/336102

and here is the  link to sample project:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/downloads/get/329346

By the way, it seems that you can't remove a column. You may need to move all the data in the cells one column to the left. Another option may be hiding or collapsing the first column.

Comment: In the documentation i am not able to find anywhere how to remove a column.

Comment: As I said, the solution is to move all the data one column to the left, or hiding or collapsing the column.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this type of solution (where hiding is just not good enough), the other option is to create a new worksheet and copy all the columns exept for the ones you want to remove, then delete the original sheet.  This is how I ended up implementing it.  There may be unintended consequences in terms of formulas, and such, but for me I just had a table full of values which worked great.

Comment: It's been 3 years, just wondering if this library ever added a way to delete or shift columns? (or both?)